# Hacer Select en todas las columnas menos en 2 especificas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo las colunnas

```
mapa, numero, mob1, mob2, mob3, mob4 asi hasta el mob400
```

En sql quiero hacer algo como decir esto

```
SELECT * NOT IN(Mapa, numero)
FROM Tabla
WHERE mapa = 1
```

se puede hacer que solo las columnas no se muestren sin tener que nombrar las otras 400?

Comment: Querido @sstan si bien el tópico es similar, creo que como habla de diferentes DBMS, no estaría mal separarlas, ¿no te parece? Por ejemplo la solución que di a esta pregunta no sé si es aplicable en MySQL.

Comment: @Pablo: Estoy de acuerdo que pueden haber soluciones diferentes por base de datos, y me alegra que hayas contribuido una respuesta. A la vez, puede que alguna de las respuestas en el "duplicado" le sirva.

Comment: Yo le haría caso a la solución de @sstan aunque te funcionen varias respuestas. Es mejor tener siempre lo más normalizada una BD, a menos que en un caso particular por rendimiento rompas las reglas. Pero no me parece tu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo personal, yo rediseñaría la tabla para que no tengas tantas columnas, tal vez dividiendo la tabla en 2, con una estructura similar a esta (obviamente, no conozco los tipos de tus campos, es solo una aproximación):

```
create table master (
  id int not null primary key,
  mapa int,
  numero int  
);

create table detail (
  id int not null primary key,
  fk_id int not null,
  mob int not null,
  seq int not null,
  constraint detail_fk foreign key (fk_id) references master(id)
);
```

De esta forma, en vez de tener una fila con `mob1, mob2, mob3, ..., mob400`, mas bien tendrías 400 registros en la segunda tabla compartiendo la misma clave foránea, pero con valores distintos para `seq`.

Esta estructura simplificaría tu problema de tener que manejar centenares de columnas en tu consulta.

---

Pero si no puedes (o no quieres) hacer el cambio, y realmente quieres hacer un `select` de todas las columnas menos esas 2, pudieras usar la técnica propuesta en esta solución: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6691661/4955425.

Resultaría en una consulta un poco complicada, pero funciona bien:

```
declare @cols varchar(max), @query varchar(max);
SELECT  @cols = STUFF
    (
        ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT '], [' + name
            FROM sys.columns
            where object_id = (
                select top 1 object_id from sys.objects
                where name = 'tbl' -- reemplaza "tbl" por el nombre de tu tabla
            )
            and name not in ('mapa', 'numero') -- excluir las 2 columnas aquí
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, ''
    ) + ']';

SELECT @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' from tbl'; -- reemplaza "tbl" por el nombre de tu tabla
EXEC (@query);
```

[Demostración](http://rextester.com/NVY16167)

---

Y una opción mas, es usar la misma técnica anterior, pero en vez de *excluir* las columnas no deseadas, pudieras solo *incluir* las columnas que comienzan por `mob`. Puede que en tu caso esto sea preferible:

```
declare @cols varchar(max), @query varchar(max);
SELECT  @cols = STUFF
    (
        ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT '], [' + name
            FROM sys.columns
            where object_id = (
                select top 1 object_id from sys.objects
                where name = 'tbl' -- reemplaza "tbl" por el nombre de tu tabla
            )
            and name like 'mob%' -- incluir las columnas que comienzan por "mob"
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 2, ''
    ) + ']';

SELECT @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' from tbl'; -- reemplaza "tbl" por el nombre de tu tabla
EXEC (@query);
```

[Demostración](http://rextester.com/UUWYH82923)

Comment: Estoy de cuerdo en que es probable que haya un problema de diseño con una tabla de 400 campos. Es como si todo el sistema fuera una sola tabla ;). Por otro lado depurar una consulta con 400 campos convertida a texto debe ser una tarea casi imposible.

Answer (score 1):

Como @Andre comentó, no es posible hacerlo de la manera

```
SELECT * NOT IN(Mapa, numero)
FROM Tabla
```

Ahora para resolverlo, podrías valerte de lo siguiente:

1. Armar una vista que solo tenga los campos que necesitas, para luego hacer

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM Vista
   ```

   Como positivo tendrás el optimizador de consultas de SQL Server actuando cada vez que llames a la vista.
2. Podrías hacerlo por medio de una tabla temporal de la siguiente manera

   ```
   SELECT * INTO #TablaTemporal
   FROM Tabla
   WHERE mapa = 1

   /* A continuación borrás las columnas que no necesitás */
   ALTER TABLE #TablaTemporal
   DROP COLUMN mapa
   ALTER TABLE #TablaTemporal
   DROP COLUMN numero

   /* Por ultimo, consultas la tabla y la borras*/
   SELECT * FROM #TablaTemporal

   DROP TABLE #TablaTemporal
   ```

   Esta solución si bien te ahorra tener que escribir todos los campos, y funciona dinámicamente (salvo que cambien los nombres de los campos **mapa** y **numero**), lo cierto es que es **muy ineficiente**, porque *cada vez* que ejecutes la consulta vas a armar una tabla temporal, llenarla, modificar su estructura, consultarla y finalmente borrarla.

Answer (score 0):

Esto no es posible, solo puedes traer todos los datos '*' o especificar las columnas que necesitas.

Si las columnas tiene un consecutivo, puedes armar el query y colocar las columnas que necesitas excluyendo "Mapa y Numero".